# Error: Database connection "Sqlite" is missing, or could not be created Cakephp 2.9.0

Tags: cakephp, mongoose, sqlite, phpdesktop

Hi I am building a desktop app using phpdesktop. I ran into this problem `Error: Database connection "Sqlite" is missing, or could not be created.` when using `cake bake`. I am able to connect to db and fetch a data-row using Controllers.

My major worry is if this problem is going to affect storing and retrieving data or any other process that is related to db functionality for the application.

I have searched the forums for info with and tried most of the recommendations but none of them seams to work. I will appreciate if anyone has information on how to solve this problem.

I a using windows and php 5.4.33. There is a variable in `php.ini` `sqlite3.extension_dir` I have tried setting this to full path and also `"."` or `"./"` none of these produced a desire result.

Comment: Try google: https://www.google.com/search?q=Error%3A+%22Database+connection%22+%22Sqlite%22+%22is+missing%22%2C+%22or+could+not+be+created.%22&btnG=Search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. It turns out that cake bake uses the current working directory for file references. In my case, I launched bake from the app directory so the database file has to be referenced relative to this folder.

My db was located in `app/data` so the right configuration to use was as shown:

```
    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlite',
        'persistent' => false,
        'database' => 'data/app_db.sqlite',
        'encoding' => 'utf-8',
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused due to wrong username / password 
or 
misspelled database name.